# Checksums via HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: https, checksums

I'm concerned that Ubuntu checksums are provided via http and not https server. I'm storing a number of iso images and time to time I run a checksum script that validates my images against the checksums. I would like to be sure that I'm getting the checksums from Ubuntu and not from somewhere else.

Moving checksums to https would make sense, and I do not think that it would be super expensive.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Your post looks like a bug report which is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: My question is why Ubuntu is not posting the checksums via https servers? I think it would be more secure.